# How can we integrate sharepoint and salesforce with or without third party app?

Tags: rest-api

How can we integrate sharepoint and salesforce with or without third party app?Any help will really helpful for me.

Comment: Did you try this...https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-integrate-sharepoint-salesforce-pratyush-kumar It might help you.......

Comment: I was trying this https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-integrate-sharepoint-salesforce-pratyush-kumar but i am not able to connect with it..